# Populate HTML table from MYSQL and counting rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to populate a HTML table with mysql data, I have the following data in Mysql:

```
ID, IP, Referal
```

I want to create a table that shows a list of the referals and how often they occur, for example:

```
ID,    IP,      Referal
1     1.1.1.1   google.com
2     2.2.2.2   google.com
3     3.3.3.3   test.com
4     4.4.4.4   another.com
```

Should output:

```
google.com     2
test.com       1
another.com    1
```

What I've tried was this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-primary">
<tbody>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM traffic";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<tr >
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php if($row['referal']==''){
echo "Empty Referal";
} else { echo $row['referal']; }?></font></td>

<td class="tc"><center><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php $referal = $row['referal'];
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM traffic WHERE referal = $referal";
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows";

?></font></center></td>

</tr>
                    <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

But that didn't count each refer individually, also it created a new table row for each entry even if the referal was the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you print the output which you are getting it from query by using this print_r($result);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `GROUP BY` keyword of SQL:

```
SELECT Referal, COUNT(*) FROM traffic GROUP BY Referal
```

This will give you exactly the table you want, without any additional for-loop in php

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that you are gathering the amount of rows found in your last query and NOT your count query:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM traffic WHERE referal = '$referal'";
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

First off, the `COUNT` command will return you a single row with a single column containing the count found. You should use the following:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM traffic WHERE referal = '$referal'";
$numResult = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
$num_rows = $numResult['count'];
```

Also, it is VERY unneeded to put quotes around a variable you are echoing. This will suffice:

```
echo $num_rows; //NOT echo "$num_rows";
```

**NOTICE:** Do not use MySQL_* functions as they have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully. It groups the count accordingly now. Although I still have the Issue that it creates a new table row for every entry, even if it is the same referal. If you can hint me in the right direction that will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: GROUP BY Referal sorted that one out, unfortunately I can't accept 2 answers :(

Comment: You can use the query @Misch suggested as the main query or use the `DISTINCT` command to grab distinct referrals